# How to read internal server graphql message?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-client

I am using Apollo Client to use graphql in android. I am trying to read response from internal server error. I can only get

> {protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url='ur'}

but actual error is

> {"errors":[{"statusCode":"503","message":"Service unavailable"}]}